# Django admin - Restrict user view by permission

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-admin, admin

I'm starting to learn Django and I have a question.

Is there any way to restric views in the administration interface? I see there are "change, "add" and "delete" permissions, but I wanted to restrict views also.

For example: Two users, "User 1" is superuser and "User 2" is in the editor group. User 1 has access to everything, but User 2 can't view a determined application in the administration.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure that User 2 has no permissions for any model related to the app you want to hide away (so no change, add or delete powers for any of the models in that app), then it won't appear in the admin for User 2.

Comment: Django is new for me,I have a same problem. where to check user 2 permission? how to check it. could you give me any referance link,please

Comment: Look in the django.contrib.auth docs for Group - that's  key here. Also ensure User2 does not have is_superuser set

Comment: I checked User2's is_superuser is not set from admin panel. but is_staff=true set. and if  I put is_staff=false it did not allow User2 to login admin section? What to do?